# Fake receipt using Unity IAP on IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

i'm trying to use the new Unity IAP to be used on iOS.

Everything goes right, I can retrieve the products defined in iTunes Connect and purchase them but I receive the following data receipt 
`{"Store":"fake","TransactionID":"2cff94fd-8470-4799-a2a5-66971888fb92","Payload":"{ \"this\" : \"is a fake receipt\" }"}` 
instead of receiving proper data.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: You always just get fake transactions / receipts in the editor.

Your best bet is to ask on the specific forum:

Here is a long post showing how to do receipt verification: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-iap-store-guides-google-play-apple-app-store-windows-store.372647/page-3#post-2566639

(Also see the posts above it with more code.)

Comment: A diffirent approach is to go through MobiShop (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/63636) we beta tested it and it works like a charm but it doesn't integrate with the Unity services, however you can still simulate billing  in the editor using some UI thats provided.

Answer (score 0):

Though my answer is not really Unity related, I can say that the only way to get a true live production receipt for an iTunes Connect purchase is through an iOS App that was **downloaded using the Store App** and **runs on a device**. If either of these is not given, the receipt will be a fake from Apple's debug store. I haven't used Unity IAP API yet, but it won't be able to procure a production receipt from iTunes Connect using a debug app any more than you will.